# Can't not write three value in 1 line

Tags: python

I was having this problem about last week in this code

```py
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
print(min(a+b,b+c,c+a))
```

- so when I enter three input like this: 2 5 6 (three interger in 1 line)
  It show me a error:

```
File "c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Code\Python\baitap(LQDOJ)\EZMIN.py", line 1, in <module>
    a = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 5 6'
```

and I see that it only identify 'a' but not identify 'b' , 'c' so can you show me how to fix it or are there other ways to write it in 1 line?

Comment: Please show your code here exactly as you have it on your own machine. Please three backticks before the first line of code and three backticks after the last line to format it as a code block.

Comment: Side-note: Is there a reason you're not just using the `min` function? Every line from 4 onwards could be replaced with just `print(min(a+b, b+c, c+a))`.

Comment: thanks for fixed my post ShadowRanger.Sorry for my mistakes this is my first question and also the first time I use this web so there are many things that I don't know much about the functions in web,I will try to figure and know it soon also thanks for your help about my code 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

The error you're encountering is because you're trying to convert the entire string '2 5 6' into an integer using the int() function. However, the int() function expects a single integer value, not a string containing multiple numbers.
code:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())

x = a + b
y = b + c
z = c + a

min_value = x
if y < min_value:
    min_value = y
if z < min_value:
    min_value = z

print("The minimum value is:", min_value)
```

**you'll be prompted to enter the values for a, b, and c separately, and the code will correctly calculate and display the minimum value among the three sums.**

**Method 2**

Using This one is more optimize solution

```
input_values = input()
input_list = list(map(int, input_values.split()))

min_value = min(input_list[0] + input_list[1], input_list[1] + input_list[2], input_list[2] + input_list[0])

print("The minimum value is:", min_value)
```

- The split() method splits the input string at spaces, creating a list of string elements.
- The map() function applies the int() function to each element of the split list, converting them into integers.
- list() is used to convert the resulting map object into a list of integers.
  The resulting list is stored in input_list for further calculations.

Comment: I understand my problem now,thank for your help 

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to convert a string that contains multiple numbers to an integer. The int() function can only convert a single number to an integer.

To fix this, you can use the split() function to split the input string into a list of strings, and then use the map() function to convert each string in the list to an integer.

```
a, b, c = map(int, input().split())
x = a + b
y = b + c
z = c + a
min = x
if y < min:
min = y
if z < min:
min = z
print(min)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python inputs to not work this way. When you use `input()`, you are telling the computer to take input from the command line until the user presses enter. Inputs are not separated by spaces. You are getting this error because the program can not parse an integer from the input `2 5 6`. AFAIK, there is not a way to put all of the inputs in one line.

A correct input would be this:

```
2
5
6
```

While pressing enter to make new lines.

Comment: The input format may be fixed, so you might want to mention how you'd write the code to *take* that format and produce the desired results.

Comment: The code he has would take this input format